# Control-M -> ENTER in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Is it possible in Eclipse to assign Control-M key to newline?
Windows XP + Helios.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for sure, not having done it myself, but investigate the key binding dialog `Window > Preferences > General > Keys`.  See page 362 of the [3.1 documentation](http://eclipse.org/documentation/) for more.

Answer (score 0):

In `Window > Preferences > General > Keys`, 
redefine `Insert new line Below current line`, and Bind `Ctrl+M`.

Be careful, by default, Control-M already toggles maximize/restore state of active view or editor. this will override the shortcut.